# How do I hover over a div box and make its first child appear?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

Here's the code followed by my question...

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dude').hover(function(){
        $('div').find(">:first-child").css( "display", "inline" );
    }, function() {
    $('div').find(">:first-child").css( "display", "hidden" );
    );
});
```

CSS

```
.dude{
    min-height:50px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="dude">ONE<div>TWO</div>three</div>
```

**When I hover over the div box with the class "dude" I'm trying to make TWO appear just so long as the user is hovering, then it goes back to hidden.**

Comment: Your only mistakes are that `hidden` should be `none` and you're missing a `}` in the `);` line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it just with CSS:

```
.dude > :first-child {
    display: none;
}

.dude:hover > :first-child {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Certainly the preferred way, just be aware of limited IE support prior to IE9 :)

Comment: IE8 supports :first-child.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.dude').hover(function(){
     $(this).children('div').first().css( "display", "inline" );
       }, function() {
     $(this).children('div').first().hide();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dude').hover(function(){
        $(this).children().eq(0).css( "display", "inline" );
    }, function() {
        $(this).children().eq(0).hide();
          });
});
```

note: you were missing a '}' to close the hover out function :)